# How can I check if the pattern of a string is present from array or not using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

Hi friends am trying to check if the pattern from the string is present in array using javascript

Here is my sample code

```
   var  senten_1 = 'amazon video'; 
   var myarray = ['video','app','login','care'];
   var last_index_item =  myarray.indexOf(senten_1);
```

index of is checking only the video. Its not checking the indexof it with amazon video. I want to remove amazon video as video is present.indexof is working if I give amazon video only in array

Comment: Let me see if I understood it correctly. `senten_1` can have multiple strings separated by a space, and you want to remove all these strings from an array, if they are present. Correct?

Comment: you forget to include what result you want.

Comment: @bugs no senten_1 is a sentence suppose it has a amazon video word in sentence and in array there is a word video if the sentence matches with any element from like pattern I should print it

Comment: Print it?  Do you mean `console.log()`?  Is it an array of sentences or just 1 string?  This question is very broad which makes it difficult to give *good* advice.

Comment: it will be single sentence

Comment: That's one question answered.  Now please explain waht you mean by `I should print it`.  Give us some context or we cannot help you.

Comment: i have multiple sentence which i pass through for loop if the sentence doesnot have a word matched from array then only it should print it

Comment: If you can't answer my questions then I will not even try to help you.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question or end result at all, but with the help of lodash includes here are some examples:

```
myarray.includes('video')
// true
myarray.includes('amazon_video')
// false
myarray.indexOf('video')
// 0
myarray.includes('amazon video')
// false
```

To print out something

```
console.log('Hello World');
```